# Working /dev/ttyS0 but can't transfer binary (one serial but two drivers Com1/Com4)

Tags: linux, drivers, serial-port, pci, serial-console

I think it's a driver config issue, it works in winXP(dual boot) with [intel drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/20018).
I'm debugging via serial port from another machine, which works fine.

The PC is a i5 dell Optiplex 790 running mint 17.1, works great.
IT has a single serial port, via PCI on the motherboad, but linux is detecting two coms port? with two drivers (PnP & PCI)

I can TTY via "screen /ttyS0 115200" and it works, i can type and i can see the replays etc, but when I go to send anything it sends a few bytes and stops.

I'm guessing linux isn't setting up the com1 correctly?
I've google'd it but I can't find anything like this.

Thanks for any help.
Cheers
Ben.

```
See command out put below from a fresh boot.
```

WINXP Settings:
Baud: 115200
Parity: None
Data Bits: 8
Stop bits: 1
Flow control: None
I/O Range: 03F8-03FF
IRQ: 04

Linux settings:
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 115200 clocal cread cs8 -cstopb -parenb
setserial /dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A port 0x03f8 irq 4

stty -a -F /dev/ttyS0
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;
eol2 = ; swtch = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke

`dmesg | egrep -i 'serial|ttys'
[    0.904757] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.925235] 00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.946748] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS4 at I/O 0x30e0 (irq = 17, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.964931] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.964935] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    0.980919] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.980923] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.409138] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.653064] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.022446] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.188610] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.355459] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.355467] usb 2-1.4: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[  458.078790] usb 2-1.7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[  458.078799] usb 2-1.7: SerialNumber: 300000000002`

cat /proc/tty/driver/serial 
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:32037 rx:12156
1: uart:unknown port:000002F8 irq:3
2: uart:unknown port:000003E8 irq:4
3: uart:unknown port:000002E8 irq:3
4: uart:16550A port:000030E0 irq:17 tx:25 rx:0 RTS|CTS|DTR|DSR|CD
5: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
6: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
7: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
8: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
9: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
10: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0

setserial /dev/ttyS0 -a
/dev/ttyS0, Line 0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
    Baud_base: 115200, close_delay: 50, divisor: 0
    closing_wait: 3000
    Flags: spd_normal skip_test

setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123456789]
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS4, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x30e0, IRQ: 17
/dev/ttyS5, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS6, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS7, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS8, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS9, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0

cat  /proc/tty/drivers
/dev/tty             /dev/tty        5       0 system:/dev/tty
/dev/console         /dev/console    5       1 system:console
/dev/ptmx            /dev/ptmx       5       2 system
/dev/vc/0            /dev/vc/0       4       0 system:vtmaster
rfcomm               /dev/rfcomm   216 0-255 serial
ttyprintk            /dev/ttyprintk   5       3 console
serial               /dev/ttyS       4 64-111 serial
pty_slave            /dev/pts      136 0-1048575 pty:slave
pty_master           /dev/ptm      128 0-1048575 pty:master
unknown              /dev/tty        4 1-63 console

cat  /proc/interrupts
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
  0:         15          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          3          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  4:       1731          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge
  8:          1          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          3          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:          4          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:         33          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
 17:    2449637          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2
 40:      10207          0          0      44417   PCI-MSI-edge      ahci
 41:       2165          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
 42:     383690          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      i915
 43:         24          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      mei_me
 44:      39322          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      snd_hda_intel
NMI:         24         19         16         17   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:     387655     267084     239854     255364   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:         24         19         16         17   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:       4561       7874       4482       4784   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          2          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:      61702      57561      22920      28286   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:        510        477        638        537   Function call interrupts
TLB:       6108      17079       8539       6852   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:         16         16         16         16   Machine check polls
ERR:          0
MIS:          0

00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 04ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR-

lspci -vs 00:16.3
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 04ad
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 30e0 [size=8]
    Memory at e1a90000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: serial

------------------ UPDATE 1 ----------------------
MINT LINUX 17.3 differences - not much

cat /proc/tty/driver/serial 
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:0 rx:0
1: uart:unknown port:000002F8 irq:3
2: uart:unknown port:000003E8 irq:4
3: uart:unknown port:000002E8 irq:3
4: uart:16550A port:000030E0 irq:17 tx:19 rx:0 CTS|DSR|CD

cat  /proc/interrupts
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
  0:         15          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          3          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  4:          3          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge
  8:          1          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          3          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:          4          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:         29          0          0          0   IO-APIC  16-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
 17:      90753          0          0          0   IO-APIC  17-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2
 24:       4983          0          0       5263   PCI-MSI-edge      0000:00:1f.2
 25:        566          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
 26:      28220          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      i915
 27:         25          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      mei_me
 28:        450          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      snd_hda_intel
NMI:          6          6          5          5   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:     101643      61501      60543      57145   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:          6          6          5          5   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          2          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:       6635       5255       3448       3592   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:        699        646        553        615   Function call interrupts
TLB:       3859       4185       2959       3659   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:          6          6          6          6   Machine check polls
HYP:          0          0          0          0   Hypervisor callback interrupts
ERR:          0
MIS:          0

lspci -vs 00:16.3 
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 04ad
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 30e0 [size=8]
    Memory at e1a90000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: serial
 ll /sys/class/tty/ttyS[012345]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:49 /sys/class/tty/ttyS0 -> ../../devices/pnp0/00:03/tty/ttyS0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:49 /sys/class/tty/ttyS1 -> ../../devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS1/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:49 /sys/class/tty/ttyS2 -> ../../devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:49 /sys/class/tty/ttyS3 -> ../../devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS3/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:49 /sys/class/tty/ttyS4 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.3/tty/ttyS4/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:49 /sys/class/tty/ttyS5 -> ../../devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS5/

ll /sys/class/tty/ttyS[012345]/device/driver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:53 /sys/class/tty/ttyS0/device/driver -> ../../../bus/pnp/drivers/serial/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:53 /sys/class/tty/ttyS1/device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/serial8250/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:53 /sys/class/tty/ttyS2/device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/serial8250/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:53 /sys/class/tty/ttyS3/device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/serial8250/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:53 /sys/class/tty/ttyS4/device/driver -> ../../../bus/pci/drivers/serial/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 14 17:53 /sys/class/tty/ttyS5/device/driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/serial8250/

enter code here

Comment: Hi, added windows settings and my linux settings and output. Still confused about the second com, windows doesn't show it.